# MedicalClinic vs. Physician

Tags: schema.org

Can anyone specifically differentiate when it is appropriate to use the http://schema.org/MedicalClinic versus the http://schema.org/Physician.

The schema.org defines each as:

**Physician**     - A doctor's office
**MedicalClinic** - A medical clinic

**The issue of contention:**  To my understanding a medical clinic is a medical business that consists of multiple physicians and other credentialed individuals.

However, isn't it possible for a physician to work for a medical clinic that's made up of a single physician & other professionals? In the case, one physician & other credentialed individuals, is it a clinic or an office?

Does clinic imply the act of treatment whereas office implies solely the act of diagnosis?

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 1):

From a practical point of view, after comparing both schemas:

- both inherits Thing > Organization > LocalBusiness > MedicalOrganization properties
- Each type properties

  - MedicalClinic:

    - availableService
    - medicalSpecialty
  - Physician

    - availableService
    - medicalSpecialty
    - **hospitalAffiliation**

So the only difference is *hospitalAffiliation* which is of *Thing > Place > CivicStructure > Hospital* type.

So if it is appropriate to fill the property hospitalAffiliation with a [Hospital](http://schema.org/Hospital) type use the http://schema.org/Physician, if it has no sense to use it, use the http://schema.org/MedicalClinic type.

Comment: So, say in the event that the leading doctor who is a part of a medical clinic has an affiliation with a hospital, would it make sense to mark-up just that page with the Physician schema and the rest with medicalClinic schema?